# Are two identity functions on different domains equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is in my book:

EXERCISE: 

Suppose $f:X→Y$ and $g:Y→Z$ and both of these are one-to-one and onto. Prove
that $(g\circ f)^{-1}$ exists and that

$(g\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$

SOLUTION:

Suppose $f: X →Y$ and $g:Y →Z$ are bijective functions, then their
composition $gof: X →Z$ is also bijective. Hence $(gof)^{-1}: Z →X$ exists.

Next, to establish $(gof)^{-1} = f^{-1}og^{-1}$, we show that

$(f^{-1}og^{-1})o(gof) = i_x$ and $(gof)o(f^{-1}og^{-1}) = i_z$

Now consider

$(f^{-1}og^{-1})o(gof) = f^{-1}o(g^{-1}o(gof))$ (associative law for o)

$= f^{-1}o((g^{-1}og)of)$ (associative law for o)

$= f^{-1}o(i_yof) (g^{-1}og = i_y)$

$= f^{-1}of (i_yof = f)$

$= i_x (f:X→Y)$

Also

$(gof)o(f^{-1}og^{-1}) = go(fo(f^{-1}og^{-1}))$ (associative law for o)

$= go((fof^{-1})og^{-1})$ (associative law for o)

$= go(i_yog^{-1}) (fof^{-1} = i_y)$

$= gog^{-1} (i_yog^{-1} = g^{-1})$

$= i_z (g:Y→Z)$

Hence $f^{-1}og-1 = (gof)^{-1}$

Now I have two questions.

 1. The procedure by itself makes sense but does this prove that $(gof)^{-1} = f^{-1}og^{-1}$

 2. are two identity functions on different domains equal

i.e. $i_x = i_y$ , $i_x: X \rightarrow Y$           $_{\text{^}}$           $i_y: Y \rightarrow Z$

Comment: Two identity functions are *not* equal, indeed they live in different spaces entirely.

Comment: You don't need to write $f^{-1}og$ or $gof$; you can write $f^{-1}\circ g$ or $g\circ f$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it does prove this.
2. No, different identity functions are not the same. The map that maps each integer to the same integer is something other than the function that maps each complex number to the same complex number. For two maps to be equal domain and codomain (in this case) must also be teh same.

Comment: but how these " $(f^{-1}og^{-1})o(gof) = i_x$ and $(gof)o(f^{-1}og^{-1}) = i_z$" prove that $(gof)^{-1} = f^{-1}og^{-1} $ ||||

Comment: Let $h:X \to  Y$ be a bijective function. Then there exists a unique function $k:Y \to X$ such that $h \circ k = i_Y$ and $k \circ h =i_X$. This function is called the inverse function of $h$ denoted $h^{-1}$. Now with $h = f \circ g$ you just showed that $k = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ has the properties we need for it to be the inverse function.

Comment: Was one part $(f^{-1}og^{-1})o(gof) = i_x$ enough or both had to be shown in order to show inverse of eachother

Comment: It is better to show both. Whether it is strictly necessary depends what you assume and how you set things up. It is possible to have a function $h$ such that there exists a $k$ with $k \circ h = i_X$ while $h \circ k$ is not $i_Y$. Yet when you already know that $h$ is bijective this is not possible anymore. In fact also the converse of my first commen is true. If you can show that such a function $k$ exists you get automatically that $h$ is bijective. (But here you really need both hok and koh).